# Vue.js How to Access Elements of an Object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an array of objects:

```
data: function() {
        return {
            customers:[],
         }
    },
```

that populates this select box:

```
         <label>DSO Affiliation:</label>
                <select  class="select-box form-control" name="customer" id="customer" v-model='customer_id' style="-webkit-appearance: none;">
                     <option value="" selected>Choose Customer</option>
                           <option v-for="customer in customers" :value="customer.id">
                                    {{ customer.customer_name }}
                           </option>
                </select>
```

Once a customer is selected I need to get the customer data from the selected object so that I can populate other form elements such as:

```
<label>Customer Address:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="cust_address" v-model='cust_address'>
```

I have the data in the `customers:[ ]` array. How do I get the customer data that was was selected in the select box without an additional trip to the server?

Comment: use a computed property to find the selected customer by `customer_id` or just bind `:value="customer"` and then your v-model property would point to the customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch the `customer_id` and update `cust_address` by filtering the `customers` array :

```
data: function() {
        return {
            customers:[],
         }
    },
watch:{
   customer_id(val){
     let found=this.customers.find(cust=>cust.id===val);
     this.cust_address=found?found.address:'';
    }
}
```